# I get an error when i try to edit a copy of a template in Visual Studio Code

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, telerik, visual-studio-2019, radwindow

Im trying to edit a copy of a template of telerik radWindow control, i just created the window and when i try to edit the template i get this error [image]  that means: "Error copying Template

Comment: Try to close VS, delete the .vs folder in the solution folder and restart VS again. Sometimes this can fix such errors

Comment: Hi Niklas, Where can i find .vs folder?

Comment: it is in the same folder as the solution is. You need to activate "show hidden elements" (or similar) in your file explorer to see the folder